# Databinding with unnamed textboxes and listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

I have been taught lately when using WPF and databinding it is good practice to not name any of the fields but only to associate them with the properties in the other classes.  My problem right now is how do I add the data from 3 textboxes (the user enters), save the binded information to the model which then posts the account information into the listbox on the side.  I need to add the data to my model. My code from main.xaml is below:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Files}" SelectedItem="{BindingPath=CurrentItem}" />

   <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=bankaccount}"/>
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=accountnumber}"/>
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=accounttype}"/>
   <Button Content="Save Data To Listbox" Click="Save_Click"/>
```

Now I will show my FileModel class which holds all of my properties which will be from the textboxes

```
        private short _BankAccount;
        private long _AccountNumber;
        private char _AccountType;

        public short bankaccount{ get { return _BankAccount;} set  {_BankAccount= value;    Notify("bankaccount"); } }
        public long accountnumber{ get { return _AccountNumber;} set {_AccountNumber= value; Notify("accountnumber"); } }
        public char accounttype{ get { return _AccountType;} set{_AccountType= value; Notify("accounttype"); } }
```

I use a class called ProgramModel As my middle point between the Mainpage and my FileModel page and here is that code:

```
 public class ProgramModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ObservableCollection<FileModel> Files { get; set; }

    private FileModel _currentItem;
    public FileModel CurrentItem { get { return _currentItem; } set { _currentItem = value; Notify("CurrentItem"); } }


    public ProgramModel()
    {
        Files = new ObservableCollection<FileModel>();
    }
```

And to finish it off I have my mainpage:

```
  internal partial class MainWindow
{

    public ProgramModel Model { get; set; }

    private ViewSettings _viewSettings = new ViewSettings();


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = Model = new ProgramModel();

        }

    private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileModel filemodel = new FileModel();

        Model.Files.Add(new FileModel( filemodel.bankaccount, filemodel.accountnumber, filemodel.accounttype));
    }
```

I feel like I am adding to the Files Collection incorrectly from the save button event. If you guys can help me out that would be great! All 3 textboxes and the listbox are on the Main page.  Let me know if you have any questions.  Also, this is a learning experience so let me know if I posted too much code or not enough.  Thanks!

Comment: Properties like `bankaccount` should be PascalCased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read the values from a new `FileModel` instance instead of from what is bound to the view. Code should be this:

```
Model.Files.Add(new FileModel
(
    Model.CurrentItem.bankaccount,
    Model.CurrentItem.accountnumber,
    Model.CurrentItem.accounttype
));
```

Make sure `CurrentItem` is actually initialized with an instance, don't see that in your code. Also, you could use a command here and have all the relevant logic in your bound view model without the need for the event.

Also, right now you bind the current item to the selected item in the `ListBox`, this will modify an existing instance instead. Not sure if this is intended. If you want those fields to be for input of new instances don't bind the `ListBox` to it.

Comment: H.B. can you explain further on the CurrentItem being initialized with an instance and how I would format that? Since I am getting the error message "Object reference not set to an instance of the object"

Comment: Just assign a new instance to `CurrentItem` in the constructor of the view model as you did with files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to answer your question directly because implementing proper data binding will take a bit of code to do so.

Using proper data binding, it is possible to have almost no code behind on your view.cs! (Specially if you start using frameworks)

Please take a look on [A Simple MVVM Example](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/) for you to follow good practice.

By following this example, you will see that you can also use data binding on buttons and other controls.

Your View Model which is `ProgramModel : INotifyPropertyChanged` should handle all the work (data processing).

Your model should not handle the UI update notifications thus,

```
public short bankaccount{ get { return _BankAccount;} set  {_BankAccount= value;    Notify("bankaccount"); } }
```

will be moved to the `ProgramModel` (View Model).

`Save_Click` method will also be converted into an ICommand and be binded to the button in view like `<Button Content="Save Data To Listbox" Command="{Binding SaveExec}"/>`

The point is, if you are studying data binding, you should implement it right. Hope you understand...

In the end, it is possible for your Main.cs to only be..

```
internal partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new ProgramModel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small change and it should work . Change Your bindings as shown below for the TextBoxes.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CurrentItem.bankaccount}"/>

<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CurrentItem.accountnumber}"/>

<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CurrentItem.accounttype}"/>
```